# Linqpad dump more than 1000 rows

Tags: linqpad

`.Dump()` only shows 1k results. How do I get it to show more than that with html formatting? The Grid results options doesn't have the formatting I need.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Taken from [this post at linqpad](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/198/result-size)

> In the GUI go to edit -> preferences -> results . At the bottom you will see "In Rich Text Mode" as well as "In DataGrid Mode". The rich text mode works on the `.Dump()` in the editor, or automating a .linq query using `.Dump()`

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old question but since I stumbled upon it.
At the top clicking this symbol will also yield a grid of all results.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if that works with automated queries or just in the editor. I haven't used linq in quite some time now.